# `Future[Option[Future[Option[X]]]]` into `Future[Option[X]]`

Tags: scala

How to transform `Future[Option[Future[Option[X]]]]` into `Future[Option[X]]`?

If it were a `TraversableOnce` instead of `Option` I'd use the [Future companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future%24); but what about Options?

Example:

```
def processAndReturnFuture(x:String):Future[String] = future(x)
def processAgainAndReturnOption(x:String):Option[String] = Some(x)

val futOpt:Future[Option[String]] = future(Some("x"))
val futOptFutOpt:Future[Option[Future[Option[String]]]] =
  futOpt.map( opt =>
    opt.map( x =>
      processAndReturnFuture(x).map( processedX =>
        processAgainAndReturnOption(processedX)
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Updated answer

This might do the trick. What I did was to replace your first two `map` calls with a `flatMap` on the outermost `Future` and a pattern match on the outermost `Option`.

```
val futOptFutOpt: Future[Option[String]] =
  futOpt.flatMap {
    case None => Future.successful(None)
    case Some(x) =>
      processAndReturnFuture(x).map {
        processedX => processAgainAndReturnOption(processedX)
      }
  }
```

#### Initial answer

I presume somewhere in your code you have a `map` call that transforms a `Future[Option[A]]` into a `Future[Option[Future[Option[X]]]]`. Replace that `map` with a `flatMap` and drop the top-most `Option` layer in the result. You'll end up with `Future[Option[X]]`. Here's what I mean:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val f1: Future[Option[Future[Option[String]]]] =
     | Future.successful(Some(1)).map(v => Some(Future.successful(Some(v.toString))))
f1: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[String]]]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@6f900132

scala> val f2: Future[Option[String]] =
     | Future.successful(Some(1)).flatMap(v => Future.successful(Some(v.toString)))
f2: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[String]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@2fac9a62
```

I'm probably not entirely correct as to what your actual context is, but you'll probably solve this by replacing a few `map`s with a few `flatMap`s.

Comment: Problem is my context does not allow me to drop that `Option` layer. I have added a code example.

Comment: To use `flatMap` I have to somehow transform it into `Future[Future[Option[Option[String]]]]`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [scalaZ](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) or [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats), you can use more generic approach, which would work for more types ( `Future` would require to have `Traverse` typeclass, and `Option` just need to be a `Monad`)

First way is:

```
  import scalaz.std.scalaFuture.futureInstance
  import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance
  import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

  val fofo: Future[Option[Future[Option[Int]]]] = Future(Option(Future(Option(5))))
  val ffoo: Future[Future[Option[Option[Int]]]] = fofo.map(_.sequence)
  val fo = fofo.map(_.sequence).join.map(_.join) // Future(Some(5))
```

Here, you first "swap" types inside future with `sequence`, and then join them together.
So for any two higher kinded types, `F[_]` and `G[_]`, where `F` - has a `Traverse` instance and `G` is a `Monad` - you can do that.
Change the `Future` to `List`, and implementation would not change.

Another way to do it, which might be interesting - is to use monad transformer.
Idea is, that in Monad you can join types together `F[F[A]] => F[A]`.

```
Future(Future(4)).join // Future(4)
Option(Option(3)).join // Option(3)
List(List(1, 2)).join  // List(1, 2)
```

If you think of `Future[Option]` as an `F` type in this context - you can join them together! All you need is just to show that Future[Option] is a monad.
ScalaZ has a monad transformer for that (the way to "compose" or assemble bigger Monads from the smaller ones).

```
import scalaz.OptionT.optionT

  val FOT = OptionT.optionTMonadPlus[Future] //creating monad transformer on top of Option
  val fo2 = FOT.join(optionT(fofo.map(_.map(optionT(_))))).run  // Future(Some(5))
```

`optionT` puts a `Future[Option]` inside a monad, so we need to do it 2 times - one for outer `Future[Option]` and one for inner `Future[Option]`

This approach would work for any types F[G[F[G]], for which you have a Monad Transformer.

We can also make it a little bit nicer and avoid this two ugly `map` inside `Future`. Map comes from `Functor` typeclass and they are composable! So we can assemble our new `Functor[Future[Option]]` and `map` over it:

```
val FOT = OptionT.optionTMonadPlus[Future]
val FOF = Functor[Future].compose[Option]
val fo2 = FOT.join(optionT(FOF.map(fofo)(optionT(_)))).run
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on the matter:

```
val futOptFutOpt: Future[Option[String]] =
  futOpt.map(_.toSeq)
    .flatMap(Future.traverse(_)(processAndReturnFuture))
    .map(_.headOption)
```

What this basically does is

1. Convert `futOpt` from a `Future[Option]` into a `Future[Seq]`
2. Process each element of the `Seq` with `processAndReturnFuture` and return a new `Future[Seq]`
3. Convert `Future[Seq]` back into a `Future[Option]`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer but a recommendation: try to avoid composing recursively, instead use for-yield

```
def someFunc(fo1: Future[Option[String]], fo2: Future[Option[String]]): Future[Option[String]] ={
    //this is what we want to avoid
    //val fofo1:Future[Option[Future[Option[String]]]] = fo1.map(o => o.map(s => fo2))

    //instead use for
    val res : Future[Option[String]] = for {
        o1 <- fo1
        o2 <- fo2
    }yield{
        println(o1 + "do what ever you want" + o2)
        //or use for a second time
        for{
            s1 <- o1
            s2 <- o2
        }yield{
            s"$o1, $o2"
        }
    }
    res
}
```