# Transform `Future[Option[X]]` into `Option[Future[X]]`

Tags: scala

How would one transform `Future[Option[X]]` into `Option[Future[X]]`?

```
val futOpt:Future[Option[Int]] = future(Some(1))
val optFut:Option[Future[Int]] = ?
```

Update:

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448779/futureoptionfutureoptionx-into-futureoptionx). I suppose I'm trying to get a grasp on elegantly transforming nested futures. I'm trying to achieve with `Option`s what can be done with `Seq`uences, where you turn a `Future[Seq[Future[Seq[X]]]]` into `Future[Future[Seq[Seq[x]]]]` and then `flatMap` the double layers. As Ionut has clarified, I have phrased the question in flipped order, it was supposed to be `Option[Future[X]]` -> `Future[Option[X]]`.

Comment: @flavian this is a followup question to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448779/futureoptionfutureoptionx-into-futureoptionx).

Comment: @flavian I have updated my question, but it seems that Ionut has already answered this for me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible without losing the non-blocking properties of the computation. It's pretty simple if you think about it. You don't know whether the result of the computation is `None` or `Some` until that `Future` has completed, so you have to `Await` on it. At that point, it makes no sense to have a `Future` anymore. You can simply return the `Option[X]`, as the `Future` has completed already.

Take a look here. It always returns `Future.successful`, which does no computation, just wraps `o` in a `Future` for no good reason.

```
def transform[A](f: Future[Option[A]]): Option[Future[A]] =
  Await.result(f, 2.seconds).map(o => Future.successful(o))
```

So, if in your context makes sense to block, you're better off using this:

```
def transform[A](f: Future[Option[A]]): Option[A] =
  Await.result(f, 2.seconds)
```

Response for comments:

```
def transform[A](o: Option[Future[A]]): Future[Option[A]] =
  o.map(f => f.map(Option(_))).getOrElse(Future.successful(None))
```

Comment: Quite right. If I were to flip the question, asking how to tranform `Option[Future[X]]` into `Future[Option[X]]`, I would still have to block on that future, correct?

Comment: No, the reverse does not hold. Updating the answer with a function that performs the reverse transformation.

Answer (score 0):

you could technically you could do this - in snippet below I use `A` context bound to a monoid so my types hold.

```scala
  def fut2Opt[A: Monoid](futOpt: Future[Option[A]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Option[Future[A]] =
    Try(futOpt.flatMap {
      case Some(a) => Future.successful(a)
      case None    => Future.fromTry(Try(Monoid[A].empty))
    }).toOption
```