# Patterns in typed functional programming Option[Future[Int]] transformed to Future[Option[Int]]

Tags: scala, monads, monad-transformers

A common situation I find myselfe in with Scala is the following flow:

1. Read some props wich returns an `Option`
2. Use the props in a `Future`
3. Make some transformation on the results in the future that returns an `Option`

This yields a type such as `Option[Future[Option[_]]]` the better solution would be using a transformation such as `Future[Option[Option[_]]]` for example using something like below:

```
def transform[A](o: Option[Future[A]]): Future[Option[A]] =
  o.map(f => f.map(Option(_))).getOrElse(Future.successful(None))
```

(Code stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450222/transform-futureoptionx-into-optionfuturex))

Then I could work with an arbitrary number of `Options` inside the `Future` using `flatmap`.

This seems like such a common pattern that im sure it is avaliable in Scala in some ideomatic way without me having to implement the transform method over and over.

So my question is: What is the most ideomatic way to turn an `Option[Future[Option[_]]]` outside in as in the above example?

Comment: A monad transformer might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Question says that you want `Option[Future[A]] => Future[Option[A]]`, but details seem to say you want `Option[Option[...Option[A]]] => Option[A]`? So, which is it? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

The `Traverse` typeclass in the cats library might help here. It can take care of the boilerplate of transforming an `Option[Future[Something]]` into a `Future[Option[Something]]`.

An example using the Ammonite REPL:

```
$ amm
Loading...
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 0.7.7
(Scala 2.11.8 Java 1.8.0_101)
@ import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-core:0.7.2`
import $ivy.$
```

First some imports...

```
@ import cats.Traverse
import cats.Traverse
@ import cats.implicits._
import cats.implicits._
@ import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
@ import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future
```

Here's the thing we want to transform:

```
@ val optionOfFuture: Option[Future[String]] = Some(Future.successful("hello"))
optionOfFuture: Option[Future[String]] = Some(scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@43ac3b45)
```

We use `Traverse`'s `sequence` method to switch around the `Option` and the `Future`:

```
@ val futureOfOption: Future[Option[String]] = Traverse[Option].sequence(optionOfFuture)
futureOfOption: Future[Option[String]] = Success(Some(hello))
```

Or if you prefer the syntax-sugared version:

```
@ import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.syntax.traverse._
@ val futureOfOption2: Future[Option[String]] = optionOfFuture.sequence
futureOfOption2: Future[Option[String]] = Success(Some(hello))
```

For more information about what else `Traverse` can do, take a look at the [cats documentation](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/traverse.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think, your problem is with #3 in your question: why do "some transformations on the result", that manipulate `Future` return an `Option`? That smells wrong. Just make them return a `Future` in the first place, and you won't have this problem.

And, by the way, I am not sure what exactly you mean by "being able to deal with an arbitrary number of options using flatMap", but it is almost certainly wrong: `flatMap` will help you get rid of *1* extra level of options *at the time of map*: `Some(Some("foo")).flatMap(x => Some(s))` yields `Some(Some("foo"))`.  `.flatten` does the same thing explicitly:
`Some(Some(Some("foo"))).flatten` yields `Some(Some("foo"))`, not `Some("foo")` or `"foo"` as you might be expecting.

Note, that in each case, there is only one level of options, the flattening deals with, not "an arbitrary number". 
The usual approach is to get rid of extra options as you encounter them (flatten right away to always have `Future[Option[T]]` rather than `Future[Option[Option[T]]]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
val a: Option[Future[Option[T]]] = ...

val b: Future[Option[T]] = a.getOrElse(Future(None))
```

Comment: Looking at the `Future` [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future$), I would choose `Future.successful` over `Future.apply`, i.e. `Future(...)`. The former notes: `Creates an already completed Future with the specified result.`, whereas the latter docs say: `Starts an asynchronous computation and returns a Future object with the result of that computation.`. Note - I'm not sure of the actual difference; just pointing to the docs.